# Returning a JSONArray from JavascriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, callback, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to return a JSONArray from JavascriptExecutor. Normally I can goto chrome browser and goto chrome's dev console and type: `"___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0]"` which returns something similiar to this:

[image]

Though when I try this:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) Browser;         
Object  o = (Object) js.executeScript("return ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0];");
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Maximum call stack size exceeded (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),
platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

Any idea of how I can overcome this?

Thanks

> UPDATE

It seems if I use:

```
 Object o = (Object) js.executeScript("return ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].Cy.C;");
```

I get back:

```
{action=null, badge=bottomright, bind=null, callback={}, content-binding=null, pool=null, preload=null, s=null, sitekey=flkgjsfldkjgsfdg, size=invisible, stoken=null, tabindex=null, theme=null, type=image}
```

which is what I am looking for, but the `Cy.C` is constantly changing. I need to be able to parse out the correct value that may change which currently is:

```
Cy.C
```

I'm assuming the value is too long? How could I correct this issue?

> Update 2

using:

```
String script = "return JSON.stringify(___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0]);";
String str = (String) js.executeScript(script);
```

returns me `unknown error: Converting circular structure to JSON`

From searching around it seems my issue may be infinite recursion? Any suggestions on how to get around this? I do not need the returned object to be in json format, I just need to be able to parse out whether through a regex expression or something else:
'Cy.C' which I can find by looking for `callback={}` or `sitekey={}` so I can build a string to call the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `unknown error: Maximum call stack size exceeded` was throwing was because the object I was searching for was way too complex.

since I saw alot of unanswered posts relating to similar things I will post what I did to solve it:

```
String script = "for (var prop in ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0])" 
               +"{"
               +" return '___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].' + prop"
               +"}";
System.out.println(script);
Object objects = (Object) js.executeScript(script);
System.out.printl(objects);
```

I am only pulling the first property here.. And from what I saw unless I iterated over the whole object I wouldn't get the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

If the return JSON object is complex, you can convert it to a string and return. Then convert the JSON string in JAVA code.

```
String script = "return JSON.stringify(___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].Cy.C);";
String str = (String) js.executeScript(script);

// Using JSON-Java lib to convert JSON string to JSON Java Object.
//
//
```

Comment: When I do that I get: 
unknown error: Converting circular structure to JSON